# Passing selected Value from options to a php variable

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to create a form in which I access several tables and offer the user choices regarding the entries through these tables.
I have a "Systems" table from which the user can choose a system.
For this purpose I have a "Users" table, from which the user can choose a user.
This data should be selected and stored in the third table "Reports".
My code looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $systemId = $_POST['systemId'];
    $userId = $_POST['userId'];
    
}

if ($db->addReport('reports', ["systemId" => $systemId, "userId" => $userId,)) {
    echo("Entry added");
}

?>


<p>Create report</p>
<form action="" method="post">
    <?php $entries = $db->getSystem(); ?>
    <div class="form">
        <label>System</label>
        <select name="systemId" class="form-control">
            <?php foreach ($entries as $option) : ?>
                <option value="<?php ($option[0]) ?>" selected="<?php ($option[0]) ?>"> <?php echo($option[0]) ?> </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I left out the part with the user for simplicity's sake, because I proceed exactly as I do with the system.

My problem is that an entry is made in the database, but the values are always "0".  However, there are also entries in the database that do not have the value 0. The correct names are shown to me in the selection context, but what is actually written to the database is wrong.

So I cannot pass the correct value to the variable "systemId".
I tried several things on the internet, unfortunately nothing worked.

Notice: the connection to the database works fine. I don't have any problems with running the querys.

Answer (score 0):

You're running the insert command even when the form hasn't been submitted. Just move that command inside the `if` statement which checks for the submitted data, so that it only runs in response to a suitable POST request.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{    
  $systemId = $_POST['systemId'];
  $userId = $_POST['userId']; 

  if($db->addReport('reports',["systemId"=> $systemId, "userId"=>$userId,)){
     echo("Entry added");
   }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not solve my problem. There are still wrong values entered

Comment: ok well that's maybe the first step in solving it then. (BTW this won't erase any wrong values previously entered, of course). Anyway your next step is to do some debugging - add some logging to this code so you can see the value of the systemId variable when it is submitted. e.g. as the simplest, add `var_dump($_POST['systemId']);` just before the `$systemId =...`line and it will show you the submitted value. Or you could log it to a file. If that seems to be correct, then maybe the problem is in the addReport function. If some IDs aren't correct, then maybe the issue is in the HTML form.

Comment: I have inserted the code and get the result "string(0) """. But the selected value was "3". So I can assume that the variable "systemId" does not get the correct value after pressing the submit button. And this is exactly where I reach my limits :)


The addReport() function does what it should. If I add a text box and don't use a select, it will report exactly the values I enter in the text box.

Comment: Like I said, that's an indication you need to check what HTML is being produced by your code. Possibly some values are missing from the options

Comment: Even  after 2 days, I couldn't solve my problem. It would be great if anyone can help me

Comment: Well, I had to add an "selected" after my value tag.  Thats all you need to do.